# How can I query a pandas dataframe for a specific value without knowing its index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have the following simple pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [['5A', 10], ['5B', 20], ['5C', 30], ['5D', 40]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Values'])
print(df)
```

which yields

```
  Name Values
0 5A   10
1 5B   20
2 5C   30
3 5D   40
```

I want to select the value of `Values` at the position of `Name=5B`, which should be `20`.  At first I implemented the following command;

```
mask = df['Name'] == '5B'
test = df.loc[mask].Values
print(test)
```

which yielded the following

```
  Values
1 20
```

However, this is a dataframe and not a value and I only want the value!  I can do the following to transform it into a value, but it requires a-priori knowledge of the index.

```
test = df.loc[mask].Values[1]
```

As mentioned, the user will never know the index of the value, they just know the value that should be queried.  With knowledge that only one value will be selected I can transform it into an array as shown and from that I know the value will always be at index 0 of the array; however, there has got to be a more elegant solution.

```
test = np.array(df.loc[mask].Values)[0]
print(test)
```

`20`

If anyone has a more elegant solution that does not involve having to create a un-needed array I would appreciate it.

Comment: If you know that there always will be one value, accessing with index 0, should not be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can index by `Name` and then use [`pd.DataFrame.at`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) for fast scalar access:

```
df = df.set_index('Name')
res = df.at['5B', 'Values']
# also possible: df.loc['5B', 'Values']
```

Where your row indexer is a series, [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) will return a series (if column filter is a scalar) or a dataframe (if column filter is a list).

As a quick guide to using `loc` with row / column labels, assuming labels are unique:

```
RowIndex    ColIndex    Result
---------------------------------
Array       Scalar      Series
Scalar      Array       Series
Array       Array       DataFrame
Scalar      Scalar      Scalar
```

Your attempt falls into the first category, since `df['Name'] == '5B'` is array-like.

Of course, you can extract the first value via `df.loc[mask, 'Values'].iloc[0]` or `df.loc[mask, 'Values'].values[0]`. However, if you know that `Name` is a unique identifier, converting it to an index will be more performant.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can just get the value using .index and .loc. The code would look like:

```
ask = df.index[df['Name']==5b][0]
test = df.loc[mask,'Values']
print(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

`df.loc[mask].Values.values` gives you an array of the values; `df.loc[mask].Values.values[0]` (or whatever index) will give you just the value.

Comment: This solution requires knowing the index of the value within the dataframe which is not known.  The solution I proposed was made based on knowledge that every value in `Value` is unique so transforming it to an array will ensure that the array only has one value and can be referenced by index 0 within the array.  However, referencing the index within the dataframe is not possible, since it is not known.

Comment: How does converting to an array ensure that the value you want will be at index 0?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way with loc:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [['5A', 10], ['5B', 20], ['5C', 30], ['5D', 40]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Values'])

value = df.loc[df['Name'] == '5B','Values'].values[0]
print(value)
> 20
```